# Aligning text above and below an image

Tags: css, image, text

I'm trying to align some text above and below an image. This set the images up nicely with the text hugging the top of the image, but the text below the image has a large space.

I would like it to again, hug the bottom of the image.

I've tried various solutions on here but to no avail.

SCREEN SHOT

[image]

Here's what I currently have.

```
div.igallery {
margin: 2px;
float: left;
width: 60px;
}

div.igallery img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}

div.idesc {
font-size:10px;
padding: 2px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Then the HTML

```
<div class="igallery">
<div class="idesc">Category F2</div>
<img title="Category F2 :: 8 Metres" src="/img/icons/safety.jpg" alt="Category 
 F2 :: 8 Metres" width="48" height="48" border="0" /><div class="idesc">8 Metres</div>

</div>
<div class="igallery">
<div class="idesc">Shots</div>
<img title="Shots :: 25" border="0" alt="Shots :: 25" src="/img/icons/shots.jpg" width="48" height="48" />
<div class="idesc">25</div>

</div>
<div class="igallery">
 <div class="idesc">Duration</div><img title="Duration :: 30s" src="/img/icons/clock.jpg" alt="Duration :: 30s" width="48" height="48" border="0" />
<div class="idesc">0:30s</div>
```

Your expertise is appreciated!

Comment: check in an inspector for styles related to the image itself, and/or look at the margins and paddings involved.  also try setting line-height: initial on your icon images, this has been an odd issue for me in the past

Comment: I can not replicate your issue. Please can you recreate your issue by using jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: You are right. I've just done a jsfiddle (first timer) and it outputs correctly. So what could be causing the gap?

Not sure how to add a Jsfiddle in here?  

https://jsfiddle.net/mdj101/Lxv3g5ex

Comment: @MDJ1 what other css do you use? Could be a conflicting issue with other stylesheets...

Comment: It's a wordpress theme for woocommerce so there could be all manor of css files, as the img isn't named as such do you think it could be this?

Comment: Oh well if it's a wordpress theme, then yes there will definitely be some css styles that are the cause of this issue. All I can suggest is get familiar with some form of Developer Tools, such as on Chrome, tap F12 to open it's Developer Tools. In this you can explore all the CSS and HTML and then some. Navigate to the images in question, and investigate the CSS rules, of each img/div set and determine what css rule is causing the issue, then you can counteract that.

Comment: I have amended my answer, due to my code was never going to work (my mistake), and to include my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin-top` to your `div.idesc` rule and set it to whatever size you want the bottom text to be away from a picture. Like so:

```css
div.igallery {
margin: 2px;
float: left;
width: 60px;
}

div.igallery img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}

div.idesc {
font-size:10px;
padding: 2px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="igallery">
<div class="idesc">Category F2</div>
<img title="Category F2 :: 8 Metres" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/469017630796296193/R-bEN4UP.png" alt="Category 
 F2 :: 8 Metres" width="48" height="48" border="0" /><div class="idesc">8 Metres</div>

</div>
<div class="igallery">
<div class="idesc">Shots</div>
<img title="Shots :: 25" border="0" alt="Shots :: 25" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/469017630796296193/R-bEN4UP.png" width="48" height="48" />
<div class="idesc">25</div>

</div>
<div class="igallery">
 <div class="idesc">Duration</div><img title="Duration :: 30s" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/469017630796296193/R-bEN4UP.png" alt="Duration :: 30s" width="48" height="48" border="0" />
<div class="idesc">0:30s</div>
```

Comment: It seems to move them further away, but using a value of 2px doesn't bring the text any closer.

Comment: @MDJ1, yes, the margin-top of 10px will move the text farther away from the image, which is what I thought you were after according to your screen shot. Do you want your bottom text far away from the images or closer to them?  This is really simple honestly, all you have to do is either adjust your padding or margin.

Comment: Sorry the image was supposed to show what it shows like now. What I want is the bottom text to be the same distance as the top text, but I can't seem to get it to do that.

Comment: @MDJ1, the code you initially posted is showing the same distance for the top and bottom text, that is 2px of padding around top and bottom text. I confirmed this on Chrome, Edge, IE, and Firefox.  In what environment does it not show the same distance?  Is it possible that you haven't included all the relevant code that would be overriding the rules you initially posted?  As it stands, the issue you posted in your screenshot cannot be replicated on desktop browsers, and the initially posted code is correct.

Comment: I've made the changes, but to no avail.

I've had a look at the code being outputted. It seems that a p tag is being inserted for the img tag and that's outputting the box at 60 x 48 creating the gap at the bottom of the image.

You can see it here.

http://www.fireworksfireworksfireworks.co.uk/product/happy-trolls/

Not sure what to use though to get rid of it.

Comment: @MDJ1, ok, so the `p` element you are talking about, the one with the `class="iicon"`, has a `margin: 0 0 10px`. If you change this to `margin: 0px`, it will remove the unwanted space or make the top and bottom space equal.

And this is why it's so important to include all the relevant code :)

Comment: You my friend are a star! I looked and looked for that but just couldn't find it. I added the following to the custom css and it's now working }
p.iicon {margin: 0 0 0 0px;
}

Comment: Glad I was able to help @MDJ1

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer would never have worked... I have amended the CSS to this:

```
.idesc:last-child { 
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

**Also, please note that you need to close the last igallery div at the end of your HTML code snippet by adding `</div>`, though I do appreciate if this was just a mistake with copy/paste.**

After discovering you are working with a wordpress theme, the above code may or may not work to the desired affect. However, to inspect this issue further, you need to delve into the Developer Tools, more info for [Chrome here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/). This is the best way to find any CSS conflicting with your layout. From doing this, you can then counteract the rules. At a guess though, the two statements you may need are as the code above: `padding-top` and `margin-top`.

Comment: Hi. This doesn't seem to make any difference. This is what I now have.

    div.igallery {
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    }

    div.igallery img {
    display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
    }

    div.igallery > div.idesc:nth-child(2) {
      padding-top: 0 !important;
    }

    div.idesc {
    font-size:10px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    }

Answer (score 0):

This is what I now have, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'm sure this is really simple, but it's got me stumped. I just want the text below the image to be the same distance from the bottom as the text on the top.

```
div.igallery {
margin: 2px;
float: left;
width: 60px;
}

div.igallery img {
display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.igallery > div.idesc:nth-child(2) {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}

div.idesc {
font-size:10px;
padding: 2px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made the changes, but to no avail.

I've had a look at the code being outputted. It seems that a p tag is being inserted for the img tag and that's outputting the box at 60 x 48 creating the gap at the bottom of the image.

You can see it here.

http://www.fireworksfireworksfireworks.co.uk/product/happy-trolls/

Not sure what to use though to get rid of it.